# Updating S3 folder name using AWS sdk for PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I am working on the S3 bucket uploads and encountered an issue.I want to update the folder name inside one of my bucket.Went through the API [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Aws/S3/S3Client.php),but did not find a solution.
       I would like to know if it is possible to achieve it or not?I would like experts over here to give inputs on it.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folders are not really folders in s3. They are just parts of the object key.

To "rename" the folder, you will need to rename all the objects inside the folder to include a different folder in its path.

Comment: I understand what you say @datasage.I know it is a flat file system.There are no actual folders,just paths separated by '/' logically.But some tools like Bucket explorer allow to edit the folder names,so I was unsure if there is an API solution to it.Also,as I understand your answer,you suggest to create an entire new folder and copy content of old objects to new.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the tools are internally copying the objects and deleting the old ones. This could take a long time if you have a lot of objects in the "folder"

Comment: Any other solution that you could suggest?There won't be many objects in my case though.Maximum I can guess won't exceed 10-15. Is that fine or too much?They would be HTML pages as I am working on hosting static sites with S3.

Comment: 10-15 is not that many. It should just take a couple of seconds to run all the API commands.

Comment: Yes,that's what I believe,and those being HTML pages the size won't be great (in KB's).Thank you,accepted your answer.I have another question regarding setting a reverse proxy for the hosted websites,pls have a look,I will be posting the link here soon

Comment: @datastage [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744741/setting-up-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-s3-hosted-websites) my other question,pls go through if possible add your comments